# Most efficient way to create Tetris-like blocks

Tags: python

I'm trying create custom shapes using the Tetris technique. For now I have 2 approaches:

```
L = [['.....',
      '...0.',
      '.000.',
      '.....',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '..00.',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '.....',
      '.000.',
      '.0...',
      '.....'],
     ['.....',
      '.00..',
      '..0..',
      '..0..',
      '.....']]
```

```
L = [[1, 2, 5, 9], [0, 4, 5, 6], [1, 5, 9, 8], [4, 5, 6, 10]]
```

Is there any more efficient way to create grid? Since I got more than 10 of those and I'll have to create at most 80 of nested lists(10 * 4directions * 2 mirrored)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use matrices as follows. It will contain a list of all the rotations of a tetris block.

```
I_Tetromino = [
        [
            [1, 1, 1, 1]
    ],
        [   
            [1],
            [1],
            [1],
            [1]
    ]
]

J_Tetromino = [
        [
            [0, 1],
            [0, 1],
            [1, 1]
    ],
        [   
            [1, 0, 0],
            [1, 1, 1]
    ],
        [
            [1, 1],
            [1, 0],
            [1, 0]
    ],
        [
            [1, 1, 1],
            [0, 0, 1]
    ]
]
```

You could make a class of block, then draw the block on the grid by its color.

Then you can render it on your screen.

This may not be the most efficient method but I prefer to use a method which is not very complicated and readable.

Edit: You can make a function also to rotate it.

```
def rot90(matrix):
    return list(zip(*matrix[::-1]))

def rot180(matrix):
    return rot90(rot90(matrix))

def rot270(matrix):
    return rot90(rot180(matrix))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what I really want is a function or method thats allows me to generate full lists of rotations quickly without manually 'draw' the shape myself. I think matrix should help but I'm not quite familiar with.

Comment: You can use ```list(zip(*matrix[::-1]))``` to rotate matrices.

Answer (score 0):

you could start with the basic shapes and build a list by applying rotations and flips to them and keeping only distinct resulting shapes:

```
def rot(M,n):
    return rot(list(map(list,zip(*reversed(M)))),n-1) if n else M

L = [ [1,1,1],
      [0,0,1] ]
I = [ [1,1,1,1] ]
S = [ [0,1,1],
      [1,1,0] ]
T = [ [1,1,1],
      [0,1,0] ]
B = [ [1,1],
      [1,1] ]

blocks  = [ rot(fb,r) for b in (L,I,S,T,B)
            for fb in (b,b[::-1])
            for r  in range(4) ]
blocks  = [ b for i,b in enumerate(blocks) if blocks.index(b)==i ] # distincts
```

output:

```
def printShape(M):
    for r in M: print(r)

for block in blocks: 
    printShape(block)
    print()

[1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1]

[0, 1]
[0, 1]
[1, 1]

[1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1]

[1, 1]
[1, 0]
[1, 0]

[0, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1]

[1, 0]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]

[1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0]

[1, 1]
[0, 1]
[0, 1]

[1, 1, 1, 1]

[1]
[1]
[1]
[1]

[0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0]

[1, 0]
[1, 1]
[0, 1]

[1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]

[0, 1]
[1, 1]
[1, 0]

[1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0]

[0, 1]
[1, 1]
[0, 1]

[0, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]

[1, 0]
[1, 1]
[1, 0]

[1, 1]
[1, 1]
```

*Note that defining these blocks as variable size 2D masks should make it much easier to implement block rendering, movements and collision detection in the game later on.*